# Angular (4 or 2) apply CSS if conditions are met

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-class

I've found some code examples that explain how I can apply a class item if conditions are met.

In my .ts file I have the following:

```
private readNews : boolean = false;
```

[..]

```
  ngOnInit() {
    localStorage.setItem('readNews', 'Read');

    if (localStorage.getItem('readNews') != null || '') {
      this.readNews = true;
    }
  }
```

In my HTML I have the following inline CSS:

```
<i class="fal fa-cogs fa-5x"></i>
```

However, what I want it to be is the following:

If `this.readNews === true`

```
<i class="fal fa-cogs fa-5x blink"></i>
```

So it needs to add 'blink' in the CSS when the news is read (which is saved in localStorage).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try like this :

```
<i [ngClass]="readNews ? 'fal fa-cogs fa-5x blink': 'fal fa-cogs fa-5x'"></i>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help of this suggestion! It made my code work. Got me on the right track. Did some changes overall too.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ngClass`

```
<i [ngClass]="(readNews == 'Read')? 'fal fa-cogs fa-5x blink':'fal fa-cogs fa-5x'" ></i>
```

or you can call custom functions

```
[ngClass]="getClass()"

getClass(flag:string) {
  let cssClasses;
  if(localStorage.getItem('readNews') == 'Read') {  
     cssClasses = {
       'fal': true,
       'fa-cogs': true,
       'fa-5x': true,
       'blink': true
     }  
  } else {  
     cssClasses = {
       'fal': true,
       'fa-cogs': true,
       'fa-5x': true,
       'blink': false
     }  
  }
  return cssClasses;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<i [class.blink]="readNews"></i>
```

Based on cheat sheet on https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet

Answer (score -1):

In HTML:

```
<i *ngIf="readNews" class="fal fa-cogs fa-5x"></i>
<i *ngIf="!readNews" class="fal fa-cogs fa-5x blink"></i>
```

And in typescript i would refactor as this to improve readability:

```
ngOnInit() {
localStorage.setItem('readNews', 'Read');
this.readNews = (localStorage.getItem('readNews') != null || '');
```

}